# North Ridge of Crib Coch grade

Tags: uk, climbing-grades, scrambling, snowdonia

I'm trying to get some info on the grade of the North ridge (going into Cwm Glas, **not the main crib coch path** but the alternative route coming from Nant Peris) of Crib Coch. I've been up Crib Coch several times but never done the north ridge. There is no footpaths marked on the maps. [This description](http://www.ukhillwalking.com/logbook/r/?i=125) of the 3000s route says:

> Eventually you should reach Crib Goch's north summit where an obvious
>   continuation descends towards the Pen y Pass, **however you need to
>   follow the ridge as it curves around to the north**. As the ridge comes
>   to an end, descend the pinkish screes in a north-westerly direction
>   via an indistinct path. Set your compass to 312 degrees and follow
>   this bearing to a steep descent down a little gully (SH 61992 56084).
>   Follow the faint path, at first to the west and then to the north
>   west, to another short descent (SH 61800 56200). Continue descending
>   in a northerly direction to cross a stream. Follow a path besides the
>   stream going downwards (north-easterly) to a good track over a bridge
>   at Blaen-y-nant. Finding the best way down from the north ridge of
>   Crib Goch is not easy and this is one section that you may wish to
>   recce first (but in reverse) from Blaen-y-nant

But I'm struggling to get a sense of the route and difficulty of this path, there's very limited information on this route on the internet. Has anyone been this way before? Any maps of the route or more detailed information anywhere? Should this require a rope, what grade is it (I'm guessing scrambling grades?)?

I think I'm going to reccy it this weekend but I'd like to have some information or other sources if possible.

Comment: Is this the route sometimes called "North Ridge via Jammed Boulder Gully" (Grade 3, per summitpost.org)?

Comment: Do you have a link I could check @requiem? I'm not sure.

Comment: Hold fire [found it](http://www.summitpost.org/crib-goch/296764)

Comment: It's the north ridge  I was after (though the jammed boulder gully look interesting). This maybe explains the confusion, there appear to be two routes a Grade I and a Grade III. I'm looking for speed so the Grade I seems like the one I'm after.

Comment: [This is exactly what I'm after](http://www.summitpost.org/north-ridge/727682)

Comment: There is also a somewhat useful description [here](http://www.welsh3000s.co.uk/snowdon.html). Although, I've never been that way.

Comment: Yeah I saw that @nivag. Though it didn't give any specifics. It's hard to get a feel for the terrain on the map or from the photo so I was a little wary, hence I wanted to know the grade. I need to move fast so anything above a Grade I would of likely slowed me down too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I walked this route the other week. It's a simple **Grade I scramble**, probably easier ground than Crib Coch itself and simple to navigate.

> Finding the best way down from the north ridge of Crib Goch is not
>   easy and this is one section that you may wish to recce first

I didn't find this an issue we simply kept moving NW until we entered Cwm Glas Mawr